# How Can I check if The Range of Start time and End Time falls into another Start time and End time that is Stored in my Data Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

After saving some Schedules for my scheduling system I need to create a code that will autocheck if my other schedules (**Start time** + **End time** + **with same  Room** + **with same Teacher**) falls with in the range of other Schedules that already saved from the Data table.

I tried to write a code but it has a problem, after getting the time that fall in the range, even the room and teacher is not the same, it counts as true... but only should be true if the Time falls into a Time range of the **same Room** + **Same teacher**.

Here is my Code:

```
String str1;

str1 = "select * from Scheduling where Timein = '" + DDStartTime.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' OR TimeOut = '" + DDEndTime.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' AND Day ='" + SchedDayDD.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";

string checkuser6 = "select count(*) from Scheduling where Timein = '" + DDStartTime.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' OR TimeOut = '" + DDEndTime.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' AND Day ='" + SchedDayDD.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'AND RoomNumber = '" + RoomDDSched.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";

SqlCommand comm6 = new SqlCommand(checkuser6, con);
temp7 = Convert.ToInt32(comm6.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

string checkuser7 = "select count(*) from Scheduling where Timein = '" + DDStartTime.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' OR TimeOut = '" + DDEndTime.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' AND Day ='" + SchedDayDD.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'AND Name = '" + SchedNameDD.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";

 SqlCommand comm7 = new SqlCommand(checkuser6, con);
 temp8 = Convert.ToInt32(comm7.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
 SqlCommand commms = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
 SqlDataReader reads = commms.ExecuteReader();

 if(temp8 != 0 )
 {
      num9 = 1;
 }

 if (temp7 == 0)
 {
      num10 = 0;
 }
 else
 {
      if (reads.Read())
      {
           tempstart = reads["Timein"].ToString();
           tempend = reads["TimeOut"].ToString();
           tempdays = reads["Day"].ToString();
           num10 = 1;
           reads.Close();
      }

      TimeSpan starts = TimeSpan.Parse(tempstart);
      TimeSpan ends = TimeSpan.Parse(tempend);

      string tempstarttime = DDStartTime.SelectedValue.ToString();
      string tempsendtime = DDEndTime.SelectedValue.ToString();

      TimeSpan nowstart = TimeSpan.Parse(tempstarttime.Remove(tempstarttime.Length - 3));
      TimeSpan nowend = TimeSpan.Parse(tempsendtime.Remove(tempsendtime.Length - 3));

      if (((nowstart > starts) || (nowstart < ends)) || ((nowend > starts) || (nowend < ends)))
      {
           num11 = 1;
      }
 }

 num12 = num9 + num10 + num11;
 reads.Close();

 if (num12 == 3)
 {
      Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts", "<script>alert('Range Between Time Conflict Detected')</script>");
 }
 else
 {
      //Save to database
 }
```

Comment: The way to find if two elements overlap or not is to test if one elements begins before the second one ends, while the second one begins before the first one ends.
It does not matter what is the data type of the elements, as long as they have measurable start and end points.
[For more information, read the wiki of the overlap tag.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/overlap/info)

Comment: I already got the overlapping in this code. the problem is that the Day, Room number and Name of teacher does not add up in the condition of the query( checkuser 6 & 7 ) what do you think is the problem in my code? and I think that on how I get the time in the datatable then compare it to the time I input is always same as what I inputted. How can I get this kind of data? ( Time Start OR Time End + Name, Day, Room ). Thanks in Advance